# Assignment as parameter in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

What is the difference between  Text(text="Hi") and Text("Hi")? 
How can I make CustomText( text = "Hi")

```
class MainActivity : Base() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Column {
                Text(text = "Hi")
                Text("Hi")

                //CustomText(text = "Hi")
                CustomText("Hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
}

open class Base : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun CustomText(inputString: String) {
        Text(
            inputString,
            style = TextStyle(color = Color.Green, fontSize = 22.sp)
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between Text(text="Hi") and Text("Hi")?

There is no difference between these.  The `text="Hi"` version is simply using a [named argument](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#named-arguments).

> How can I make CustomText( text = "Hi")

Your `CustomText` needs a `String` argument named `text`.  That is, you should change

```
fun CustomText(inputString: String) {
```

to

```
fun CustomText(text: String) {
```